# Proposal for harder/more specific challenges

Tags: discussion, questions, challenge

Eventually, we might run out of topics for the normal challenge. We still have at least 1 year with the current proposals, other proposals can be added and we could also recycle the old ones.

They are called challenge but are not really challenging. I had an idea the other day while browsing the challenge suggestions. I saw several topic with an equal number of votes. I thought that maybe we should could do a challenge with 2 or multiple tags applied together.  Questions featured in this challenge will need to cover both topics. Just as an example [mythical-creatures](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mythical-creatures) and [hard-science](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hard-science) would be a good combination: Can a supernatural ability be explained with science? It could lead to some very interesting or bizarre combinations and make things more challenging.

This challenge could be set to take part separately form the usual challenge or in alternation.

Note: I used [hard-science](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hard-science) but it does not have to about specifically about science.

Answer (score 3):

The idea of the tag challenge is not that it's challenging for one person to write one question. It's a challenge to the community as a whole to work together to raise the profile and activity in that tag. As a mark of success most tags that have been in a challenge have now either passed or are close to reaching the 100 question point which makes them eligible for giving out tag badges.

I don't see the benefit in making the challenge harder for individuals to contribute to, that just takes it away from the community and makes it more of an elitist pursuit.

Comment: I'm not proposing that we should cancel the other one but add a more challenging contest for those who feel up for it.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Tim's answer about the challenges being for the *community*.

That said, if you want to add a separate challenge that's harder for the individual users, one way to do that might be to run a concurrent challenge using one of the tags in the current topic challenge (and another that you choose).  If the current challenge is, say, [moons](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moons), go ahead and propose a concurrent challenge for, say, [moons](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moons) + [society](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/society).  You can get a pretty good idea of what the next few challenges will be from the current votes, so you can work up a few additional challenges and be ready to go when the time comes.